# Cleaning up a String in Visual Basic - Those Annoying Rectangles

Tags: vb.net, file-io, notepad

Can anyone give me some advice as to how to clean up a string in Visual Basic .NET? I'm creating a string as a report with line breaks. However, the string is built based off of screen scrapes from a TN3270 emulator. The string is saved successfully with all of the data I require, but those annoying rectangle symbols show up once I send it to a notepad text file. Do you know anyway I can strip those out and clean up the output? [image: Example of my Output]

Comment: "Those annoying rectangles" would be characters not recognized by your current encoding.  Do you know what they are supposed to be?  The answer may have to do with changing the encoding to something that includes that character.  Of course, Notepad probably isn't doing you any favors either.

Comment: I believe the rectangles are supposed to be tabs.

Comment: They look like new-lines to me, you can see the same format line follows them every time: ID CHAR DATE

Comment: Is there anyway I can replace them with newlines?

Comment: Maybe I'll have to .trim each line as I add it to the string? And then I could add a vbCrLf. Hm...

Comment: if it's tabs, replace `vbTab` with `vbCrLf` but I'm telling you, that's not tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s.Replace(vbCr, vbCrLf);
```

Replace `vbCr` with `vbLf` depending on what is in your file.

Alternatively, just open it in WordPad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft's VBScript scripting library
This allows you to use regex in vb6

For more help refer to

[How to use Regular Expressions in Visual Basic](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html)